# Rails Change record values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, records

I have a record in postgresql of user status it is boolean and its attributes are "true" and "false". I want to show "true" as "active and "false" as "inactive". How do I do it with query or any thing to add in model.

Controller:

```
     def index
     @users = User.reorder("id ASC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
     @count = 0
     end
```

Model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :order_statuses

     attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, :code

     validates :first_name, presence: true
     validates :last_name, presence: true
     VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
     validates :password, length: { minimum: 6}

    has_secure_password
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
     before_create :create_remember_token

    def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end

     private

     def create_remember_token
     self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
      end
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this method in your model, and when you call `@user.status`, it will show 'Active' or "Inactive".

```
def status
  self.status?  ?  "Active" : "Inactive"
end
```

Hope, It will help. Thanks

Comment: Above code was giving me unrecognized error so i modified it a bit:def User.status
    self.status  ?  "Active" : "Inactive"
  end    Problem is it is still not changing the values to active. Thanks for the help

Comment: you defined it as a class method, you don't need to do this. Please paste your error here.

Comment: Well it is solved I wrote the function directly into the index page. Thanx again.

Comment: index page? you mean index view. never write your functions in views.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to display to your users "active" instead of true and "inactive" instead of false.

You could do something like this in all your views:

```
@user.status? ? 'active' : 'inactive'
```

Or if you need this in a bunch of places you could write a helper:

```
module UserHelper
  def status_text(user)
    @user.status? ? 'active' : 'inactive'
  end
end

# and call it from your views like this:

<%= status_text(@user) %>
```

Or you could put that into a model method if you need this function only in conjunction with the user and it's active method (as per Rails Guy's suggestion)

Lastly you could use I18n to translate the string for you if you have a mulitlingual page:

```
# en.yml
en:
  status:
    true: 'active'
    false: 'inactive'

# user_helper.rb
def status_text(user)
  I18n.t("statys.#{user.status.to_s}")
end
```